# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called on tableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am using tableView in a viewcontroller1 and implementing a didSelectRowAtIndexPath for moving to viewController2 with some data and displaying it on a tableView on viewController2...for now everything is ok, but then when I implement the code on viewController2:

```
     (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath) {

    // some code
}
```

After I selecting a row its selected and colored in blue but never stop's in the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set not only the data source of the table view to your view controller, but the delegate also:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Should I set it on the viewController2? and where exactlly..in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @vadim think a bit about it. You should set it in the initialization of the view controller in which there is the table view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate of your tableView, either in your storyboard or XIB file, or programatically.